# How can i generate a Url in PHP with typenum 21

Tags: php, typo3-8.x

I have a question. I would like to create in my empty function a url with the typum 23 in PHP. I am currently working with Postman and need to create an url for the query. After I have created the url, I can generate the code and query it with Postman. Is there any way to create that in my Function? Thanks for your Help

Comment: What's `typenum 23`? Or 21?

Comment: its the end of the Url example: omain.de/index.php?id=1&type=100

Comment: It is, sadly, completely unclear to me what you're trying to achieve or what you've done so far.

Comment: Hi @Kommunist24 and welcome to SO. Can you please provide some of your code and try to explain us what result are you trying to achieve?